# Can formating C drive and installing ubuntu make data lost in other drives?

Tags: 18.04

I have windows 10 installed currently on my C drive. I want to install ubuntu on it replacing windows 10. How can I do that properly? Aslo, If I formate and install on it, will it make any changes to my data in other drives?

Comment: Backup all data you don't want to lose.

Comment: It should not touch data on other partitions, BUT boo-boos happen all the time(one reason for this site).  Do what mikewhatever says.

Comment: "How can I do that properly?" Why do you ask when we all know everyone makes regular backups. There is not 1 valid reason to not backup anything important.

Comment: @Rinzwind I don't have much experience using ubuntu. Before asking here I did some search. I found many commands. Fix parts, gdisk and more. I got confuse, so a proper way might be a safe way not losing data and get ubuntu running without any errors. Yeah, I understand making backup is always an option

Comment: No, backups are not an option. Backups are -mandatory-. Always. There is no excuse for not having a backup.  You even make backups when not messing around with partitions or filesystems.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for your  help and support, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Installing a new Operating System is *inherently risky*. While the Ubuntu developers work hard to ensure data doesn't get erased, they have not tried to install on your particular hardware.

Also, one of the install options is to *erase all data and reformat the entire drive*, and humans sometimes make erroneous selections that they later regret.

Best practice is to back up ALL data that you value on the entire drive onto some other media before changing partitions or installing a new OS. Being prepared for problems can save you days of misery.